# Locust passing headers

Tags: header, token, locust

Is it possible to have Locust pass a header command with a secure token to load test an API?

I am trying to test our api for an encoder with a header flag for a token as the server being tested has to receive a token with the request, ie.

curl -H “Authorization: Token token string” http://someserver

Comment: How are you doing this currently?  `self.client.get(uri, headers={“Authorization": 
"Token token string”})` should work

Comment: I will give that a try and report back, thanks

Comment: what about if basic auth? @enderland

Comment: @uberrebu you'd instead use the `auth` field, e.g. `auth=("username", "password")` and leave the `headers` field as `None`.

Comment: actually got it eventually after searching around..yup correct...thanks!

Answer (score 45):

Yes, you can use:

```python
token_string = "token string"

resp = self.client.post(
            url="http://someserver",
            data=json.dumps(data),
            auth=None,
            headers={"authorization": "Token " + token_string},
            name="http://someserver",
        )
```

Answer (score 29):

Additionally, if you want to use same headers for every request you can also set them to the client in the `on_start` method. They will be automatically used with every client request.

```py
class User(HttpUser):

    def on_start(self):
        self.client.headers = {'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'}

    @task
    def my_authenticated_task(self):
        self.client.post('enspoint')  # this will use headers we set earlier
```

Comment: How do you do this for FastHttpUser?

Answer (score 1):

```
class User(HttpUser):

    host = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'      
    @task
    def predict_post(self):
        self.client.post("/route/", data=json.dumps({
        "text": "finish all the track to hear and great good tune u do a great job alan walker",
        "max_op_words": 10,
        "max_time": 1,
        "max_predictions": 1
        }),auth=None,
        headers={"authtoken":"your-auth-token", 'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

I was missing out on content-type header and was getting a 401 error authorization error.